# JQuery sortables, how to keep sorting after ajax request_

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

So, I am doing a laravel project where I am using Jquery sortables to sort some data and then using ajax to update the order in my database.
laravel blade code

```
<div id="gallery" style="width: 80%">
    <div id="image-container">
        <ul id="product-list" >
            @foreach ($images as $key=>$image)
                <li id="product_{{$key}}"  class="inline-block" style="width: 20%">
                    <img id="li_product_{{$key}}" src="s3 source">
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var dropIndex;
        $("#product-list").sortable({
            update: function(event, ui) { 
                dropIndex = ui.item.index();
                var productIdsArray = [];
                var i = 0;
                $('#product-list li').each(function (index) {
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var split_id = id.split("_");
                    productIdsArray .push(parseInt(split_id[1]));
                });
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    url: "/update",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        productIds: productIdsArray, 
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

It is working fine for the first time...updating data in the databse. and If I refresh the page and try again, it is fine. But If I keep changing order without refreshing, then it is not changing the dom...and the order is getting messed up. I need to know, how do I keep sorting the order without refreshing the page properly.

Comment: Have you checked if the browser console is showing any errors? You are not modifying the DOM in response to your AJAX request there - so I don't see how that could be the culprit. If you replaced the whole `update` callback function with one that does nothing more but log something to console, I am guessing you still have the same problem?

Comment: I think, I need to modify the dom in ajax request. I am appending to productIdsArray  from the dom. So, if I change once, let's say first image in list is moved to third place. And it is updated in the db...so, image 1 becomes 3. But according to dom before refresh, it is still with id product_3. So, If I change again, without refreshing the page, it cause problem. And no there is no error on console log.

Comment: @CBroe I tried modifying the DOM in ajax. But cannot seem to get it work with sortables.

Comment: `$('#product-list').load(document.URL +  ' #product-list');` I have tried using this in ajax success. But then sortable doesn't work with it.

Comment: Because that replaces the content of the `#product-list` element - so you would have to initialize the sortable plugin on that element again then. But why are you doing this in the first place? You just reordered your items on the client side, sent that new order to the server, and presumably(?) have the server return the elements in that new order now with that request - so you would be replacing the items with the same items in the same order they are already in, what's the point of that?

Comment: Because I can have up to 10 elements in my product lists. And user may reoreder several. Dragging and dropping one after another. I am updating my contents in ajax after every drag and drop. So, it gets messy when user xtries to reorder several elements.

Comment: And how is the number relevant? Are you not showing all elements at the same time? _"And user may reoreder several. Dragging and dropping one after another."_ - so after that, the elements _are_ in a specific order on the client side now. You send that order to the server, get the elements back in that same order now (I am assuming that's the case - yes, or no?) - and replace the elements on the client side, that already _were_ in that order, with the same elements _in_ that same order.

Comment: I am showing all elements together. But there is no button. So reorder o\any, it sends ajax request and orders the list. You cannot wait till you reorder 3 or 4 elements.

Comment: But that _still_ doesn't explain, why you need to _replace_ the elements with what comes back from the server?

Comment: That's the requirement...

Comment: Because that replaces the content of the #product-list element - so you would have to initialize the sortable plugin on that element again then.  How to do that @CBroe

Comment: The "requirement" is to do nonsensical stuff that doesn't actually change anything? How weird. _"How to do that"_ - well the same way you initialized it to begin with - `$("#product-list").sortable(...)`

Comment: @CBroe do I stop before the ajax call?

Comment: Huh, "stop" what? You would have to do this after the `.load()` call, because that is what replaces the existing elements with new ones. (And since `load` is also asynchronous, "after" would actually mean, in the `complete` callback.)

Comment: It seems there is some serious gap in my understanding. anyway thanks for your time..